# TimeOnly field on form locked but not disabled

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I've added a DateTime field and made it show only time without date on my main form. The mian form has other fields as well like lookup, text fields and default DateTime fields. I'm trying to disable all the fields on form load event using this code:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control, i) {
    if (control && control.getDisabled && !control.getDisabled()) {
        control.setDisabled(true);
    }
});
```

The problem that I'm facing is that all the fields are disabling except the time only field on the form. Although the field show the lock icon but I can still change the time in the field and only after pressing ctrl+f5 on my browser the timeonly fields gets properly disabled.

[image]

This is how I've set time only property to a DateTime field on my form:

[image]

Comment: the problem is that to show just the time portion I am quite sure you are using unsupported code, so probably the Xrm control collection is not able to disable it

Comment: @GuidoPreite, There isnt any code to show only time. It's done through CRM by going into the DateTime field properties then controls and selecting time without date.

Comment: then you are probably using a PCF control to show just the portion of the date (like this one https://pcf.gallery/d365datetimebox/) feel free to put a screenshot of the setting you are changing, but afaik the OOB datetime control doesn't allow to display only the time, and if you don't have the OOB datetime control, the setDisabled method doesn't work.

Comment: @GuidoPreite, I've edited my question and added a screenshot. Please have a look.

Comment: your screenshot confirms that you are using a PCF (called "Time without Date"), if you know the author (maybe has been developed internally by your company) they may help you with providing a setting that disable it on request (for example by checking the status of the original field). hope it helps